# Entity Framework Adding Namespace

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am now using Visual Studio 2013. I have recently reinstalled a machine and am having a problem with Entity Framework when I 'Update Model From Database'
The original app was developed on VS2010 then VS2012 and now VS2013
EF keeps adding a new namespace in the edmx designer.

Namespace ComfortGroupModel

.......

End Namespace

I then get over 100 errors come up. It seems my context no longer can be found.
I then remove the namespace and alter a couple of other bits of code and I am away.

So is there any way I can fix this?
Thanks in advance
Scott

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what components throw these errors?

- If it's code that depends on T4 generated CLR types, I suggest you refactor it properly to accommodate the new namespace. Pragmatically, it's normally just a matter of adding a few `using` statements or prefixes.
- If it's internal to the EDMX model (mappings, ...), you may try to change the namespace yourself by modifying the `Namespace` property (section `Schema`) for the EDMX model in the Visual Studio designer. Alternatively, you may edit the EDMX file yourself.

*I've actually recently renamed a namespace that way for unrelated reasons. Again, from a practical point of view, it usually comes down to some search and replace.*

Comment: Thank you. It appears that VS 2013 creates a namespace if one wasn;t used. I am getting around it by adding a ton of using statements to point to the context. Scott